# Hover over one div, change color of another but fade out all divs that aren't hovered on

Tags: css, html, fadeout

I've trimmed down what im trying to achieve so its easier to follow.

Ok so i have three divs as follows (All aligned horizontally)

```
<div id="MainGrid">
    <div id="Row1">
        <div id="row1floatleft">
        </div>
        <div id="row1floatRight">
        </div>
        <div id="row1floatMiddle">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I mouse over row1floatleft it changes the background color of row1floatmiddle this is working perfectly, the problem im having is trying to fade out the row1floatright div

this is my css

```
#MainGrid
{

 width:900px;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:1px solid black;   
}

#Row1
{
 width:900px;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:1px solid blue;   
}

#row1floatleft
{
width:299px;
float:left;
height:150px;
border:1px solid red;
background-color:Red;
}

#row1floatRight
{
width:299px;
float:right;
height:150px;
border:1px solid yellow;
background-color:Yellow;
}

#row1floatMiddle
{
width:299x;
height:150px;
border:1px solid green;
background-color:Green;
}

#row1floatleft:hover ~ #row1floatMiddle
{
background-color:Blue;
}
```

I'm trying to replicate this 
http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/us/en/the-virgin-experience.html

So i mouse over the row1floatleft it changs the back ground color of row1floatMiddle but needs to fade out all other divs that aren't hovered on, I've tried not(:Hover)

```
#row1:not(:Hover)
{
background-color:Orange;
}
```

but that doesnt interact with the

```
  #row1floatleft:hover ~ #row1floatMiddle
{
background-color:Blue;
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fLJZv/1/

There was an error in your css:

```
#row1floatMiddle
 {
   width:299x;
 }
```

Missing the 'p' for pixels.

I've added some more CSS:

```
#row1floatMiddle
  {
     margin: 0 0 0 299px;
  }
```

And

```
#row1floatleft:hover ~ #row1floatMiddle
{
opacity: 0.5;
}
#row1floatleft:hover ~ #row1floatRight
{
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The fiddle (at least) now works . . .

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, I see you are fading out the other two divs that aren't hovered, I just need to fade out one so I hover over div one it changes the color of div 2 BUT fades out div 3

Comment: Exactly what it does here http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/us/en/the-virgin-experience.html

Comment: Simple, change the hover event for div 2 back to a colour change like you had it before (it's an opacity at the moment) - #row1floatleft:hover ~ #row1floatMiddle{ background-color: blue; } - My fault for not reading the brief properly !!

Comment: Thanks Pat Dobson looks really good, ill follow the same way you have done it when i come to add more rows :) theres going to 12 divs in total so ill hover div 1 show div 2 and fade out the other ten! thanks again

Comment: Just had a thought wont the CSS look a mess doing it that way?

Comment: Yes, the CSS will look a mess. There might be a way to make it less verbose - welcome to the world of minimisation !